# Functions whose gradient-descent paths are geodesics

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control

Let $f(x,y)$ define a surface $S$
in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a unique local minimum at $b \in S$.
Suppose [gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) from any start point $a \in S$
follows a geodesic on $S$ from $a$ to $b$.
(**Q1**.)
What is the class of functions/surfaces
whose gradient-descent paths are geodesics?

Certainly if $S$ is a surface of revolution
about a $z$-vertical line through $b$,
its "meridians"
are geodesics, and these would be the paths followed
by gradient descent down to $b$.
So the class of surfaces includes surfaces of
revolution.  But surely it is wider than that?

(**Q2**.)
One could ask the same question about paths followed by
[Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization), which in general are different from gradient-descent
paths, as indicated in this Wikipedia image:

      
[image: Newton's vs. Gradient]
*Gradient descent: green.
Newton's method: red.*

(**Q3**.) These questions make sense in arbitrary dimensions,
although my primary interest is for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Any ideas on how to formulate my question as constraints on $f(\;)$,
or pointers to relevant literature,
would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Let me add a fourth side to the question. (**Q4**.) Let $h:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ be smooth and increasing. Let $f$ be a function as in (Q1). Is $h\circ f$ such a function too ?

Comment: @Denis: I see your motivation. Excellent question! 

Comment: Solutions $s$ to the eikonal equation $|ds|=1$ always have geodesics as gradient flow lines, and their level sets are perpendicular to those geodesics. This gives you quite a few examples. The geodesics perpendicular to a hypersurface are always locally given by solving the eikonal equation ($s$ is the oriented distance to the hypersurface).

Comment: The eikonal equation story, for example, gives you Joseph O'Rourke's example below.

Answer (score 20):

For (Q1). The tangent space of $S$ is generated by the gradient flow vector field $v = (|\nabla f|^2, \nabla f)$ and the tangents to the level sets $w= (0, \nabla^\perp f)$. The geodesic constraint can be imposed as the condition "no sideways acceleration", which means that $[(\nabla f \cdot \nabla )v] \cdot w = 0$. This implies that $\nabla^2_{ij} f \nabla^if \nabla^{(\perp)j}f = 0$. In other words, the eigendirections of the Hessian of $f$ must be $\nabla f$ and its orthogonal, or that $\nabla f$ is parallel to $\nabla |\nabla f|^2$. So this means that **$f$ and $|\nabla f|^2$ share the same level sets**. (This same characterization is valid for any dimension; so also answers (Q3). )

In particular, this answers Denis Serre's (Q4) in the positive.

Comment: @Willie: That is a beautiful characterization, that $f$ and the square
gradient share the same level sets! I do not yet see what this implies in terms of the global geometric shape of $f$, but it certainly is a succinct encapsulation.  Thanks!

Comment: Two functions share the same level sets iff the values of each of them only depend on the values of the other. So Willie's condition writes as an eikonal equation $|\nabla f(x)|^2=h(f(x)),$ and I guess that solutions are all of the form $f(x)=g(\mathbb{dist}(x,C)),$ at least locally ($g$ and $h$ being related by $1/h= (g^{-1})^')$. Here $\mathbb{dist}(x,C)$ is the point-set Euclidean distance from $C$.

Comment: @Pietro: And $C$ is ... ?

Comment: (I guess) $C$ could be any subset, even not smooth, for the distance function from $C$ is 1-Lipschitz, thus differentiable a.e., and $|\nabla d_C|=1$, so in any case one gets a solution. A smooth, convex $C$ should give solutions defined everywhere. Note that $C$ a point gives the surfaces of revolutions you mentioned in the questions.

Comment: (sorry, I changed notation: $d_C(x)=\mathbb{dist}(x,C)$). Another way to characterize the functions $f$ should be, that sublevel sets {f<c} are uniform neighborhoods of $C$ (or of any sublevel set {f<b}, with b<c).

Comment: @Pietro: Thanks for spelling out the consequences for me!  I am starting to see (sorry for being slow) ...

Comment: I think Q4 should imply that $f$ is rotationally symmetric. Imagine using a function $h$ so that $h\circ f$ is nearly flat. Then the gradient flow lines of $f$ on $S$ are nearly planar geodesics, so the gradient flow lines of $f$ in the $xy$ plane should be planar geodesics (by taking a geometric limit). Then the level sets of $f$ (in the plane) should be circles. I haven't thought about how to make this heuristic rigorous yet. 

Comment: I'm starting to get this. Instead of a square in Pietro's construction as the set on which $f$ is zero, take an ellipse. Instead of the distance or the squared distance, start with the fourth power of the distance. If that works out alright, take $g(d) = d^4 e^{-1/d}$ to get a $C^\infty$ example.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function $f(x,y)$ which is 0 inside the square $C=[\pm1,\pm1]$,
and outside that square
has value equal to the Euclidean distance $d( p, C )$ from $p=(x,y)$ to the boundary of $C$.
[I am trying to follow Pietro Majer's suggestion, as far as I understand it.]
It is not a surface of revolution
(but it is centrally symmetric).
Are its gradient descent paths geodesics?
I think so...

[image: Function, Contours]

*Left above*: $f(x,y)$. *Right above*: Level sets of $f$.
*Below*: $\nabla f$.

[image: Gradient]

And here (*below*) is a closeup of the function defined using squared distance
$[d( p, C )]^2$, as per Willie Wong's suggestion:

[image: WW]

Comment: Hmmm, like Jeopardy, :) your answer is in the form of a question...  I think they just might be, but now in this case, there is no point that is a unique minimum.  Everything within the square $C$ is the minimum.  So what is your gradient descending to?  The closest point in $C$ to your starting point?  So you've got 4 voronoi cells defined by (0.5,0) (0,0.5) (-0.5,0) and (0,-0.5) for E/N/W/S directions, which delineate the four regions closest to the 4 edges of $C$,except for any point within $C$ in which case its gradient descent is the point itself.

Comment: @sleepless: Yes, no unique local min, but still one can define descent paths for all points exterior to the central square. Your description is accurate, including answer$=$question!

Comment: Or, you've got 8 regions, with the 4 quadrants translated (+/-0.5, +/-0.5) in the xy plane  with gradient descents  for any point in those planes mapping to the corners of the square $C$, e.g. (x≥0.5,y≥0.5)→(+0.5,+0.5), and the other three quadrants where you swap in less-than signs for -0.5 values all having gradient descents as lines going to the corners of the square $C$; and the regions for x > 0.5 and $-0.5 \le y \le 0.5$ having a gradient descent to $(y,0.5)$, and three other similar regions mapping to the edges of the region $C$

Comment: So the answer in this case, is a definite YES, the gradient descents for this figure for any point starting outside of $C$ are definitely geodesics.  I'd call this figure a circle fractured into quadrants intercalated by strips of the plane defined by a square at the center of the fractured circle quadrants.  (instead of drawing the contours of the distance, draw the gradient of the function and you'll see it clearly.)  

Comment: By the way, this function certainly is rotationally symmetric about the $z$-axis with 4-fold symmetry.

Comment: @sleepless: Perhaps I misinterpreted the meaning of "rotationally symmetric." Edited now to avoid that term.

Comment: Joseph, in order to get a $C^1$ surface what you want to do is take the  **squared** distance from the square $C.$ That way you still get your geodesics, and nine pieces: $C$ itself, four parabolic cylinders $ z= ( x \pm 1)^2$ or $ z= ( y \pm 1)^2$  , four rotational  sections $ z = ( x \pm 1)^2 + y \pm 1)^2.$ So this is just slicing things up. Ask your question demanding $z = f(x,y)$ with $f \in C^3$ and then $ f \in C^\omega$ and see what happens. I will be working on $C^\omega.$

Comment: By the way, as sleepless says, the gradient/geodesics work in your initial version, you have a square, four planar half-strips, and four sections of a round cone. 

Comment: I'm starting to get this. Instead of a square in Pietro's construction as the set on which $f$ is zero, take an ellipse. Instead of the distance or the squared distance, start with the fourth power of the distance. If that works out alright, take $g(d) = d^4 e^{-1/d}$ to get a $C^\infty$ example.